# Show Custom List Data in Approval Task

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom-list, workflow-tasks-list

I have created a travel approval site where the user types in their data and a workflow creates an approval task for each manager as it moves along. The task  "Workflow Task (SharePoint 2013)", shows the basic task information but management wants the task page to also show data from the list as well.They would also like the manager to have the ability to type in notes on the task page that the employee will see once the task is approved/denied.

I am able to include the information they want in the email that is sent out via the task process but when the task page come up those columns are blank. If data is typed into those fields it also does not save. I don't quite understand the "Look up for String" box even after watching numerous videos and reading a few help pages. I am sure it is something simple to import/save this data but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I would like to avoid using JS if possible to gather this information.

This is the email that is sent out via the task and the fields they want to see on the task page.

[image: Task Approval Email]

Thank you,
Steve

Comment: could you include an image of your WF settings?

Comment: @MeladFrancis Thank you for your response. I think I may have found a workaround by formatting the information I need to show into the description field since from what I have gathered it will be a challenge to add and populate these fields.

Comment: Also, I need to include a comments field so the person approving/denying can type in notes. Per a previous post I found at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fd2e5f6a-6a6f-492a-89af-e92a39f18b83/how-to-get-approver-comments-captured-in-workflow-tasklist-sp2013?forum=sharepointcustomization they used a 2010 wf to make it work. I would like to stick to a 2013 work wf to keep it cleaner. Could something like this work under the "app step"?

Comment: WF Screenshots. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYkGd.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWm9Q.jpg. This is the formatting code I used to fix the description box, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-text-in-a-text-field-5EF9C9B5-B964-4C14-9E94-FD210715C444.

Comment: @MeladFrancis I did not have a TaskID variable. I created a "Set" action to add it to the variable but I do not know if that is what you were looking for. I then added the lookup to the email but it is still not pulling the data. When the email comes in, that field is blank. I have tried saving the task with data in that field and also just clicking approved. Nothing. I posted screenshots. What am I missing?

Comment: Here are the links to the screen shots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGDUu.jpg
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg5NV.jpg

Comment: hmm... this is my skype ´live:meladfrancis´ we can arrange a kinde of "Go-together session" to check your workflow together if you like

Comment: That would be great. How long are you around for? I will not be in the office for another 2hrs or so, which would make it around 4ish there. I can try then or if you have some other suggestions for what I can try, I will do that. Thank you so much!

Comment: I ended up having to: Pause for 0 days, 0 hours, 1 minutes
 then "Set Variable: Comments to Association: Task List:Comments. Then I put in an Update list item to update the comments field with the variable comments. After, that adding in the variable:comments to the email worked fine. Thank you.

Comment: Here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A53PK.jpg

Comment: greate job Steve -:)

Comment: @MeladFrancis: You helpful for this issue. Think you could offer any guidance on this post? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213245/local-variables-not-showing-as-an-option-under-task-outcome-to-variable-in-w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took what @Melad Francis stated above and ended up having to:

- `Pause for 0 days, 0 hours, 1 minutes` then
- "`Set Variable: Comments to Association: Task List:Comments`. Then
- I put in an `Update list item` to update the comments field with the variable comments.
- After, that adding in the `variable:comments` to the email worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

To add a comment into mail body you need to `Add a lookup` inside it you will configure it like this

[image]

this will give you a ability to write a comment and send it to Task-Travel creater

Hope this would help you :)